# which algorithm will be good for detecting and recognition of faces from variety of angles

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, open-source, object-detection

i am building a face recognition app for my class attendance system , i collect training data from social website like facebook, instagram and other, as you can see the images i got from there is not usually front facial but at variety of angle. i was using haar_cascade for face detection , but it is not good for tilted face, can anyone suggest me the good algorithm for face detection through which i can detect face at variety of angle.